# Python, Sqlalchemy and pandas encoding

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to get the data from a .db file into pandas in python through create_engine from Sqlalchemy. The problem is that I always get the following error :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError)
Could not decode to UTF-8 column 'SameAs2' with text 'Carb�n nacional'
```

I am creating an engine with sqlalchemy like this :

```
db = create_engine('sqlite:///'+dir_path+'\\results.db',echo=True,encoding="latin1")
```

and then I connect to it like this :

```
my_parameter = pd.read_sql_table("SameAs", db)
```

I am trying to change the encoding in the create_engine part, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: did you try 'utf-8' as encoding? Also possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235696/pandas-to-sql-gives-unicode-decode-error

Comment: The other one handles mysql not sqlite. I don't know if there is any difference regarding the connection string between the 2. Utf-8 is the standard encoding. The problem is that I have a Spanish character í.