# Problem with inserts data from Python (to_sql) to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pandas-to-sql

I have some problems with symbol `#`.

Some data in columns contains the symbol `#`, for example

```
'JRE#150' 
'July banner #150'
```

When I am inserting data from file all.csv into SQL Server, records containing this character are not inserted into the table correctly.

What do I mean?!

If I try to insert this value 'JRE#150', only this part 'JRE' is stored, NULL is inserted into other columns.

How the process looks like and what I am doing:

1. The first independent engine sends me the `all.csv` file from the API to DataFrame.

   The following line is responsible for importing this data into a file.

   .csv is:

   ```
    df.to_csv(r'C:\\...\all.csv',  encoding='utf-8', index=False)
   ```
2. Second independent mechanism is doing this:

   ```
    df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\\...\all.csv', sep=',', comment='#', encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)

    df.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists = 'replace', chunksize = None, index=False)
   ```

How to insert data into SQL Server with `#`, do not replace for another symbol or delete?

What is the problem here and how can I fix it?

I will be grateful for the help.

Comment: I've never heard of this before. I just Googled it now and found this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235696/pandas-to-sql-gives-unicode-decode-error

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `comment='#'` parameter from `pd.read_csv(...)`.

As per the Pandas [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) documentation:

> **comment: str, optional**
>
> Indicates remainder of line should not be parsed. If found at the beginning of a line, the line will be ignored altogether. This parameter must be a single character. Like empty lines (as long as `skip_blank_lines=True`), fully commented lines are ignored by the parameter header but not by skiprows. For example, if `comment='#'`, parsing `#empty\na,b,c\n1,2,3` with `header=0` will result in `a,b,c` being treated as the header.